# Factorial in haiku!

Tags: math, popularity-contest, source-layout, factorial

### Task

Create a program that calculates the factorial of a number using no built-in factorial functions. Easy? The catch is that you must write your entire program (including testing it) in [haiku](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haiku) form.

[image: Not enough work]
You can use as many haikus as you need, but when pronounced, they must follow the 5-7-5 syllable format.

#### Scoring

This is a [popularity-contest](/questions/tagged/popularity-contest), so you must get the most upvotes to win. Your program must consist of at least one full haiku, and all haikus must be complete.

When reading code, the first line of each haiku will have 5 syllables, the second will have 7, and the third will have 5.

Comment: Sounds like a perfect fit for something written in Shakespeare: http://shakespearelang.sourceforge.net/report/shakespeare/shakespeare.html

Comment: It seems most answers are ignoring "*including testing it*".

Comment: I like how you link to a site that correctly says the important thing for Haiku are (a) *kiru* and (b) a seasonal reference and then only ask for the more or less optional part of counting *mora* (or syllables in a language that doesn’t really have *mora*. 

Comment: I agree with @ChristopherCreutzig -- it would be much more interesting if we had to ensure a seasonal reference and cutting. Sadly, we often overlook these fundamentals of haiku. Seems to me that `then` or punctuation could aid in cutting. For *kigo*, not so sure...

Comment: I am no expert to Haikus, but there is certainly some lyrical quality expected. So far I only see [one answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/21171/16713) that has any.

Comment: `String[] myWords = { "some words",\n"seven syllables here",\n"another five here"};` (I should use morae, but some words can't be split, thus I use syllables.)

Comment: @SebastianH /about your comment:/lyrical quality - Perl?/That must be a first!/

Comment: IK it's quite late, but I hope you guys know there is an OS called Haiku? Code for it would fit here perfectly. Actually, most C++ programs are compatible with it...

Answer (score 57, accepted):

## Smalltalk

(evaluate in a workspace; opens a dialog, asks for a number and prints the result on stdout):

```
"in" "this" 'poem,' "you" "must"
"pronounce" "characters" "like" "these:"
"return(^)," "and" "times(*);" "please".

"but" 'never' "in" "here"
"tell" "anyone" "about" "those"
"few" "parentheses".

"otherwise" "these" "words" 
"are" "stupid" "and" "this" "coded" 
"rhyme" "is" "wasted" Time.

"let" "us" "now" "begin" 
"by" "defining," "in" Object
"and" compile: "the" "rhyme:"

'fac: "with" arg"ument"
"to" "compare" arg <"against" 2 ">"
"and" ifTrue: [ ^"return"

"["1] "or" ifFalse: "then"
["return"^ arg *"times" "the" "result"
"of" ("my"self ")getting"

"the" fac:"torial"
"of" "the" "number" arg "minus"-
1 "[(yes," "its" "easy")]'.

("Let" "me" "my"self "ask"
"for" "a" "number," "to" "compute"
"the" fac:"torial"

("by" "opening" "a" 
"nice" Dialog "which" "sends" "a"
request: "asking" "for"

'the Number to use' 
"(which" "is" "(" "treated" ) asNumber)
"then" print "the" "result".
```

I tried to bring in some reflection ("in this poem") and kigo as well.
Also, some western style rhyme elements are included (please->these, time->rhyme); however, being neither native speaker of Japanese, nor of English, forgive any stylistic details ;-)

Comment: BTW: To try in Squeak/Pharo, replace "Dialog" by "FillInTheBlankMorph" and "print" by "inspect".

Answer (score 41):

## Java - 2 haikus

```
protected static
        int factorial(int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return n + 1;
    } return factorial(n
            - 1) * n;}
```

Even when the question isn't [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), I often catch myself golfing the answer. In this case, I golfed the number of haikus.

I pronounce it so:

> protected static
> int factorial int n
> if n is zero
>
> return n plus one
> return factorial n
> minus one times n

---

Test program:

```
class Factorial {                                    // class Factorial
    public static void main(String[]                 // public static void main string
            command_line_run_args) {                 // command line run args
        
        int i = 0;                                   // int i is zero
        while (7 != 0)                               // while seven is not zero
            System.out.                              // System dot out dot

                    println(i + "!"                  // print line i plus not
                            + " = " + factorial(     // plus is plus factorial
                            i += 1));}               // i plus equals 1

    protected static
            int factorial(int n) {
        if (n == 0) {
            return n + 1;
        } return factorial(n
                - 1) * n;}}
```

Note that this program starts outputting `0`s fast; that is a result of overflow. You could easily get larger correct numbers by changing each `int` to `long`.

Standard pronunciations for `System.out.println` and `public static void main(String[] args)` are reflected in the program.

Comment: Sorry for the unupvote; I want to boost the Haskell solution

Answer (score 41):

### Haskell

```
fact :: Int -> Int          -- fact is Int to Int
fact x = product (range x)  -- fact x is product range x
range x = [1..x]            -- range x is 1 [pause] x
```

Haskell education time:

- The `range x` function creates a list of integers from 1 up to the value of `x`.
- The `fact x` function multiplies all the values of the list `range x` together to compute the result.
- The first line says that the `fact` function takes an integer and returns an integer.

Comment: Umm... `Int` is limited to 32 bits or so. Surely you don't want to use `Integer`?

Comment: missing the point somewhat @JanDvorak?

Comment: No. I realise they amount to a different amount of syllables and thus a drop-in replacement isn't possible. What I'm asking for is a Haskell entry that doesn't overflow :-) (and yes, I like even this one)

Comment: Form over function. If this were real programming I would certainly account for the overflow case :)

Comment: `range x is 1 to x` is 6 syllables though

Comment: Oh jeez! I can't believe I didn't notice (and apparently neither did 22 other people).

Comment: @David I read it as "range x is one [dramatic pause] x".

Comment: Honestly, that's how I read it in my head and that's why I didn't notice!

Comment: Good lord. It's a single haiku and it's elegant. I have got to learn Haskell.

Comment: I highly recommend [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters) if you'd like to learn you a Haskell.

Answer (score 28):

## APL

```
factorial←{×/⍳⍵}
```

> Factorial is—
>   the product of naturals
>   up to omega

Comment: +1 for the <- functioning as a kireji, whether you knew that was what you were doing or not.

Comment: @JonathanVanMatre LOL not even a clue! I did use a dictionary to count the syllables though (not a native speaker.) I added a dash to show the kireji.

Comment: +1 for also being both simple and euphonious in English.

Comment: Simple, yet beautiful.

Comment: Save a three bytes: `factorial←×/⍳` "up to the input".

Answer (score 21):

## Shakespeare

```
The Products of Love:
A haiku tragedy with
mathy undertones.

Romeo, a man.
Juliet, a maiden fair.
Friar John, a monk.

Act I: A Cycle.
Scene I: Pertinent Values.
[Enter Romeo]

[Enter Friar John]
Romeo: Listen to thy
heart. Thou art thyself.

Friar John: Thou art
as forthright as a songbird.
[Exit Friar John]

[Enter Juliet]
Romeo: Thou art as fair
as a violet.

Scene II: Questioning
Themselves. [Exit Juliet]
[Enter Friar John]

Friar John: Art thou
as just as the sum of me
and a nobleman?

Romeo: If so,
let us proceed to scene III.
[Exit Friar John]

[Enter Juliet]
Romeo: Thou art as good
as the product of

thyself and myself.
Juliet: Thou art as fierce
as the sum of an

eagle and thyself.
We must return to scene II.
Scene III: A Lengthy

Title for a Brief
Dénouement; Or, The Last Word.
[Exit Friar John]

[Enter Juliet]
Romeo: Open your heart.
[Exit Romeo]
```

An (imagined) test case:

Despite its length, this program just takes a single integer as input and provides a single integer as output. So:

```
6 ↵ 720
7 ↵ 5040
0 ↵ 1    1 ↵ 1
```

("Six, seven-twenty. / Seven, five thousand forty. / Zero, one. One, one.")

Comment: I'm not sure how I feel about the fact that I can tell this is legit code.

Answer (score 12):

## Python 2, 4 Haikus

A complete Python 2 program `haifac.py`. Run as `python haifac.py <n>`

```
#run this full program
import operator as\
op; import sys#tem

#please provide an arg
n = sys.argv[1]
def haifac (n):

    if n < 1:
        return 1#to me at once
    else:#do something else

        return op.mul(
            n, haifac(n - 1))
print haifac(int(n))
```

Pronounciation:

> run this full program 
> import operator as 
> op import system
>
> please provide an arg 
> n equals sys arg v 1 
> define hai fac n
>
> if n less than 1 
> return 1 to me at once 
> else do something else
>
> return op dot mul 
> n hai fac n minus 1 
> print hai fac int n

Comment: I like the use of `#to me at once` to make the meter work...

Comment: And me likes the escaped newline in the beginning :)

Comment: I think using comments is kind of like cheating.

Answer (score 9):

### GolfScript, 2 Haikus

```
),{0>},{,,*}*
```

Read as haiku, enumerating each keystroke:

```
#close parenthesis
#comma open-brace zero
#greater-than close-brace

#comma open-brace
#comma comma asterisk
#close-brace asterisk
```

With test case (5 haikus):

```
[1 2 3]4+          #generate the array [1 2 3 4]
{                  #start creating block
),{0>},{,,*}*      #actual factorial code
}%                 #close block and map across array (so that we should have [1! 2! 3! 4!])
[1 2 6]2.3**12++=  #generate the array [1 2 6 24] and check for equality
```

Read as haiku:

```
#open-bracket one
#space two space three close-bracket
#four plus open-brace

#close parenthesis
#comma open-brace zero
#greater-than close-brace

#comma open-brace
#comma comma asterisk
#close-brace asterisk

#close-brace percent-sign
#open-bracket one space two
#space six close-bracket

#two period three
#asterisk asterisk one
#two plus plus equals
```

Answer (score 9):

## [Whitespace](http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/download.php)

This makes uses of one of the [most famous](https://whrarchives.wordpress.com/2011/09/01/a-contrarian-view-of-bashos-frog/) *haiku*s, and [a great deal](http://www.ahapoetry.com/AHI%20frog%20art.html) has been written about it.

No idea why nobody has done this before, [it doesn't even take any effort!](http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/examples.php)

First of all, before reading the poem, I want you to lean back, relax, and enjoy the tranquility created by the great void surrounding the poem. It emphasizes the pond, surrounded by a vast landscape.

```
古池や    
蛙飛びこむ               
水の音
```

[source code on filebin](http://filebin.ca/1tdvROHWP8cN)

In case you do not speak Japanese, this [is pronounced](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hepburn_romanization) as follows:

> fu ru i ke ya
>
> ka wa zu to bi ko mu
>
> mi zu no o to

Naturally, it is counted by morae. The [*kireji* is や (*ya*)](http://kogumaza.jp/1410haikujihyuu.html), the [*kigo* (seasonal reference) is 蛙 (*kawazu*, frog, -> spring)](http://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%B5%E3%82%8B%E3%81%84%E3%81%91%E3%82%84).

Using the linux interpreter from the official page, you can use it like this:

> $ echo 5 | ./wspace .ws

Answer (score 8):

## PHP, 4 haikus

*All-in-rhyme* haikus!

```
function haiku($can) { // function haiku can (5)
    if ($can == 1) // if can is equal to one (7)
        return ++$stun; // return increase stun (5)

    if ($can == 0) { // if can equals ou (5)
        echo "It is one, you know! "; //echo "It is one, you know! " (7)
        return 1+$blow; } //return one plus blow (5)

    if ($can > $fun) { //if can exceeds fun (5)
        return haiku($can-1) //return haiku can less one (7)
            *$can; }} //multiplied by can (5)

if (null == $knee) { // if null equals knee (5)
    $free=0+3; // free equals zero plus three (7)
    echo haiku($free); } // echo haiku free (5)
```

Comment: I read line three `return plus plus stun`.

Comment: I really like this one.

Answer (score 8):

## Forth

```
: fugu 1              \ colon fugu one                = 5
swap 1 + 1 ?do        \ swap one plus one question do = 7
i * loop ;            \ eye star loop semi            = 5
```

*Fugu* is the function and my attempt at *kigo*: blowfish is a winter reference.  I intend `?do` to be *kireji*, the turning point, before the counted loop.

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica

```
f[x_]:=     (* f of x defined *)
 x f[x-1]   (* x times f of x less 1 *)
f[1]=1      (* Mogami River *)
```

Pedants may read the last line as "f of 1 is 1", but I couldn't resist the shout-out to Basho.

#### Testing:

```
Table[f[n],     (* Table f of n *)
 {n, 1, 10, 1}] (* n from 1 to 10 by 1 *)
ListLogPlot[%]  (* ListLogPlot output *)
```

#### Returning:

```
(1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720, 5040, 40320, 362880, 3628800)
```

[image: log plot of values]

#### Linguistic Distinctiveness Bonus Haiku (inspired by @cormullion)

```
Rewrite any term
High-level functions abound —
Mathematica
```

Answer (score 5):

### Batch

```
@set /a t=1 &^
for /L %%a in (2, 1, %1) ^
do @set /a t*=%%a
```

**Pronunciation**; ignores mathematical expressions as well as these symbols `@ / % ^ , ( )`:

> set a t 1 and
>  for L a in 2 1 1
>  do set a t a

Note; this calculates the factorial, it doesn't output it - the variable `t` contains the factorial.

The following Haiku / code can be appended to the same batch file to output the factorial (the `|`'s are pronounced as pipe):

```
@echo %t% ||^
When will you learn, unclemeat ^
Why must you use Batch?
```

Answer (score 5):

## Clojure

```
(->> *command-line-args*                ; thrush com-mand line args
  seq last read-string range (map inc)  ; seq last read string range map inc
  (reduce *) println)                   ; re-duce times print-lin
```

Answer (score 5):

#### newLISP

The parentheses are not pronounced:

```
(define (fac n (so))            ; define fac n so 
(if (= n 0) 1                   ; if equals n zero 1
(* n (fac (dec n)))))           ; times n fac dec n

(for (n 0 10)                   ; for n zero ten
; let's test from zero to ten
(println (fac n thus)))         ; printline fac n thus
```

> Lisp code consists of
>
> numerous parentheses
>
> and a few functions

Comment: Love the commentary haiku. Taking it as inspiration and adding one to my answer.

Answer (score 5):

## F#

```
let fact n =
    [1..n] |>
    Seq.fold (*) 1
```

> let fact of n be
>     from one up to n, apply
>     Seq dot fold star one

Comment: stole mine... ;)

Answer (score 5):

## [LiveScript](http://livescript.net/)

This one's medieval:

```
prelude = ^^ do                       # prelude is clone do
  require \prelude-ls                 # require prelude dash ls
{ product } = prelude                 # product is prelude

story = (ah) ->                       # story is ah such:
  ones-misery = (one) ->              # one's misery is one such
    let death = product               # let death be product

      fight = [1 to one]              # fight is one to one
      why = (one) -> death <| fight   # why is one such death take fight
  ones-misery ah                      # one's misery ah

room = console.log                    # room is console log
room <| (story 10)!                   # room take story three bang
[null of { use : this }]              # no of use is this
```

Prints `3628800`, which is `10!`. It's a little roundabout: The function `story` returns a function `ones-misery`, which always returns the answer. It's artsier that way.

No filler comments or unnecessary strings!

---

Bonus debugging story:

> I burst out laughing
>   
> when informed that a bug was
>   
> "`death` is `undefined`"

Comment: Haha, you wouldn't have hit that bug if you had "death = !proud".  http://www.poetryfoundation.org/poem/173363

Answer (score 5):

### Haskell

This one will be a **rhyming** haiku!

```
fact 0=1                     --fact zero is one
fact ton=ton * (fact stun)   --fact ton is ton times fact stun
        where stun=pred ton  --where stun is pred ton
```

Yeah!

Note: Pred means the previous number. Also in haskell, you can have multiple definitions of a function, and the first one that makes sense is used.

Comment: Elegant! (filler)

Answer (score 4):

**Ruby - One Haiku**

```
ARGV.first.to_i.
 tap do |please| puts 1.upto(
 please ).inject( :*) end
```

Read (ignoring punctuation, but including one emoticon) like this:

```
 arg vee first to i
   tap do please puts one up to
 please inject smile end
```

Comment: Produces no output for 0!.

Comment: @200_success: Thanks. I may have to live with that, it's not strictly in the requirements, so I will have a think

Comment: Also the test is meant to be haiku. I missed that on my first read myself.

Comment: @Jonathan Van Matre: Yes I missed it too. Seems even the top answers are not bothering with this. As mine is on the command line, it is tricky to get multi-lines, I guess I should remove the test for now to make it a canonically ok answer though . . .

Answer (score 4):

In SML:

```
fun fact 0 = 1
  | fact n = n*fact(n-1)
  ;
```

read as:

```
"fun fact 0 is one,
bar that, fact n is n times
fact of n less one"
```

Answer (score 4):

## Perl

```
$r = 1; for(1           # r gets one for one
.. pop @ARGV) { $r *=   # to pop arg v r splat gets
$_; } print $r;         # the default print r
```

Toss this into a file named `f.pl`

And the output:

```
$ perl f.pl 3
6$ perl f.pl 1-1
1$ perl f.pl 10
3628800$
```

Which is read as:

```
perl f p l three
perl f p l one less one
perl f p l ten
```

Comment: How do you pronounce the testing in 7-5-7?

Comment: @ChristopherCreutzig I can get 5 and 6 in there nicely for testing ('perl f p l three' (5) and 'perl f p l ze-ro' (6))... I can't quite figure out a clean 7 one that shows the necessary tests.

Comment: @ChristopherCreutzig Figured out a trick for it.  Thank you for reminding me of that requirement.  (Though, to be fair, 1-1 doesn't actually test '0', just gives the same result - it works for zero too though)

Answer (score 3):

### Perl

I know it's against the rules to use ready-made functions, but here's what I get.

Imagine your task is to instruct an over-sized rodent:

```
use Math::BigRat; use
feature 'say'; use warnings; say
new Math::BigRat($_)->bfac
```

I can only guess what the last word means and how it's pronounced, but I assure you it is one syllable. Apparently he doesn't understand what you want from him, so you have to elaborate (easing on quality standards as you loose patience):

```
use Math::BaseConvert
':all'; no strict subs; no warnings;
reset and say fact($_)
```

still to no avail. Then you have to explain it in plain English:

```
no strict; no warnings;
use Math::Combinatorics;
say factorial($_)
```

What happened next I don't know, but code is valid:

```
perl -nE 'use Math::BigRat; use feature "say"; use warnings; say new Math::BigRat($_)->bfac'
42
1405006117752879898543142606244511569936384000000000
```

and

```
perl -nE 'use Math::BaseConvert ":all"; no strict subs; no warnings; reset and say fact($_)'
33
8683317618811886495518194401280000000
```

and

```
perl -nE 'no strict; no warnings; use Math::Combinatorics; say factorial($_)'
16
20922789888000
```

Comment: "I assure you it is one syllable" :)

Comment: Too bad you can't toss a [Coy](http://search.cpan.org/~dconway/Coy-0.05/lib/Coy.pm) error in there.

Comment: This is the only answer so far that has any lyrical quality :)

Comment: @SebastianH, thanks :), though I cheated while others tried to play by the rules

Answer (score 2):

#### Python

```
lambda n: reduce(
    lambda a, b: a * b,
    range(1, n), n)
```

The way I read it:

> ```
> lambda n: reduce
> lambda a b: a times b
> range 1 to n, n
> ```

`

Comment: Produces buggy output for 0!.

Answer (score 2):

**C**

```
#include <std\
io.h> 
#include \
<stdlib.h>

int main(int argc
 , char** argv)
{   // iteratively
    // compute factorial here
long int n = \
0, i \
= 0, r = \
1 /*
product starts at one*/;

if (argc 
> 1) { n = 
strtol(argv[\
1], NULL, 10)
; if (n 
< 0) {
       printf("Arg must\
       be >= 0\n");
       exit(-
    1);}
} i = 
n;
while (i) { r 
= r * i;
    i
--;
} /* print
the result*/ printf(
"%d factorial\
equals %d\
\n", n
, r);
/*done*/}
```

**Pronounciation:**

pound include standard
I/O dot h pound include
standard lib dot h

int main int arg c
comma char star star arg v
open brace comment

iteratively
compute factorial here
long int n equals

zero comma i
equals zero comma r
equals one comment

product starts at one
semicolon if arg c
is greater than one

open brace n is
str-to-l of arg v sub
one comma NULL comma ten

semicolon if
 
n less than zero begin
printf arg must

be greater than or
 
equal to zero backslash
n semicolon

exit negative
 
one semicolon end brace
end brace i equals

n semicolon
while i open brace r
equals r times i

semicolon i
decrement semicolon
close brace comment print

the result printf
percent d factorial
 
equals percent d

whack n comma n
 
comma r semicolon
comment done end brace

Comment: The `#` character is typically pronounced *sharp* or *octothorpe* in C code.

Answer (score 2):

## Python

Uses  a single haiku to do the job!

```py
f = lambda x:   \ #  f is lambda x:
    0**x or x * \ #    zero pow x, or x times
    f(x-1)        #    f(x minus 1)
```

This defines a recursive lambda which calculates the factorial - `0**x` handles the case of 0 as it evaluates to `1`.

Answer (score 1):

Are we allowed to use filler?

Python 2 haikus:

```
number = num + 1
a = 13 + 4
b = 14

nuum = len([1])
for i in range(1, number):
    nuum *= i
```

Comment: `nuum equals length one`?

Comment: length of the list

Comment: I'm asking for your pronunciation of the first line. `num equals length of the list` makes 7 syllabes instead of 5.

Comment: You could replace `nuum` with `foo` (because I'm reading if as nu-um, which puts you over the limit.)

Answer (score 1):

### C# - 3 haikus

I removed the usual C# using, namespace and class definition clutter, which would be a 4th haiku.

```
public static void
Main(){int num = Convert.
ToInt32

(Console.ReadLine());
 Console.WriteLine(num ==
 0 ? 1 :

Enumerable.
Range(1, num).Aggregate
((i, j) => i * j));}
```

which I read as

```
public static void 
Main int num equals Convert
To int thirty-two

Console dot Read line
Console Write line num equals
zero? then one, else

Enumerable
Range 1 to num aggregate
i j i times j
```

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell

```
module Haiku where          -- read literally.
fac x = let in do           -- = is read as 'equals'
product [1..x]              -- product one to x
```

note that the module .. where is added automatically to any Haskell code without it at compilation, so not writing it is practically cheating.

Comment: Until today I had no idea you could enter a single statement under `do` and it didn't have to be `Monad a => a`.

Answer (score 1):

**C**

Least beautiful haiku ever.

```
int main(int argc,           
char *argv[]){int in,out;
sscanf(argv

[1],"%d",
&in);out=1;while 
(in > 

1){out*=
in--;}printf(
"%d",out);}//done

/*
Int main, int argc,
char star argv. Int in out.
Sscanf argv 

sub one, percent d, 
and in. Out equals one. While 
in is greater than

one, out times equals
in minus minus. Printf
percent d out. Done
*/
```

Comment: How do you pronounce `char *argv[]){int in,out;` to have it 7 syllables? I count 5-6, depending on pronounciation of `argv`...

Comment: as in the comments:  'char star arg-v. int in out'

Comment: Erm... totally missed the comments, was used to have them right to the code by the other answers :D Nevermind.

Answer (score 1):

**JAVA:**

In response to the question and to the Dwaiku (Double-Haiku or whatever you wanna call it) posted by Quincunx in Java, here's the correct Haiku:

```
public static int factorial(int n) {
   return (n==0) ? (n+1) : (factorial(n-1) * n);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Javascript - Two Haikus

```
function factor (a) {          // function factor a
  if(!a){ return 1 ||          // if not a return 1 or
    a & 17}                    // a and seventeen

  else if (a + 1){             // else if a plus one 
    return a * factor          // return a into factor
    (a + ( - 1) )  }}          // a plus minus one
```

I am not a native speaker. So, I used a dictionary to count the syllables. Hopefully, it's good enough. Any feedback is welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

**Powershell, 2 Haikus**

```
function facto ($num){    # function facto num
$i = 1; 1..$num|          # i equals one; i to num
foreach { $i =            # for each i equals

$i * $_}; write $i}       # i times this write i
$answer = facto $args[    # answer equals facto args
0]; write $answer         # zero write answer
```

Answer (score 1):

**Befunge-93**

Three haikus:

```
0&>:v
-:|:>1>
v#>$\
>:>>v
>$.@v<<
^#v*_
#>>>v
<<:\<>^
<#<#<
```

Last line is admittedly kind of cheaty.

Try here: http://www.bedroomlan.org/tools/befunge-93-playground

Answer (score 1):

## Perl - 3 Haikus

This one useds some clever formatting and pronunciations - it also disregards symbols.

```
print "Enter number: ";
chomp(my $num = <STDIN>);
$result = 1;
for $x (1..$num) {
  $new = $x * $result;
  $result = $new;
}
if (1) { print "$result\n .
Is the factorial of\n";
if ($result) { print "$num"; }
```

Haiku:

> Print: En-ter num-ber
>      Chomp: my num e-quals STD (stand)-IN
>      Re-sult e-quals one
>      For x one to num (or 'one range num')
>      New e-quals x times re-sult
>      re-sult e-quals new
>      If one: print re-sult
>      Is the fac-to-ri-al of
>      If re-sult: print num

Let me know if I messed up anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica - One Haiku (+1 extra (2 counting title))

```
factorial[n_]
 := Product @@
  Range[1, n]
```

> fac-tor-i-al en
>
> set de-layed pro-duct ap-ply
>
> range from one to en

From some simple words

Complex functions can arise

Mathematica

Answer (score 1):

## C (GCC), 4 haikus

```c
int fac(int number) { // int fac int number
        if (number == 0) { // if number equals zero
                puts("Done."); return 1; // puts done return one
        }

        else return number // else return number
                * fac(number - 1); // times fac number minus one
        puts("Unreachable"); // puts unreachable
}

main(argc, argv) // main arg-c arg-v
        char ** argv; { // char pointer pointer arg-v
        char c = getchar(); // char c is getchar

        printf("%" // print-f ampersand
                "d", fac(c - '0')); // d fac c minus zero
        return +0; // return plus zero
}
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##bVHBboQgEL37FROSZsGuXffQk/HWX@gHsDhaEkULsoc2@@0WEDEbywGGN@/NDA9RdEIsi1QztFxQfyo73FAz@IXLBWIC9kQGcckW6ApBXUO5CdrIA/y2vDfwg3pMmm1NdjaUfIwK3wirQONstYJr5Sv4HDQutcEuTAUeWQqxN4kSWzr1ET00z8NTo6SAKwttZzmgCW@NmUEqa56ar1N/Ko1cfPFbj4TtE9sdztyUA5eKct2JM7j9zjzPY/5WiLDfU2En05DngVmtPgZoGp3vuJ//qATU0OHsY7pOE2FpNny3bNKuTkvJCwlj@1vRAh8m1Iar5uAUacg5mCWcT6fyxNYOTbBJRIeePjg6/1oGYrxN/UZ7LMv7Hw)

Answer (score 0):

### Python 2

```
print(reduce(lambda              # print reduce lambda
    a,b: a * b, range(1,         # a b a times b range one
        1 + input()), 1))        # one plus input, one
```

Comment: When input is 0, `TypeError: reduce() of empty sequence with no initial value`

Comment: @200_success: `0! = 1` is just a convention ;)

Comment: Now it works, but the last line has six syllables.

Answer (score 0):

## Clojure

```
(defn fact [n] (if                  # def-fun fact n if
  (zero? n) 1                       # zero question mark n 1
  (* n (fact (dec n)))))            # times n fact dec n
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python - Two Haikus

```
val = int(input())        -> val is int(input())
for hi in range(1,n):   -> for hi in range one to n
    val *= hi           -> val is val times hi

# Still a cool haiku    -> Just read it
print(n)                -> print val in parentheses
# Completed haiku       -> Just read it
```

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/EyyW/0)